# How can I review a deleted answer that did not (to the best of my knowledge) violate any guidelines?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969800/why-is-pip-installing-pillow-for-os-x-10-12-when-i-have-os-x-10-11-installed) question had two answers ~15 hours ago, but I was unable to evaluate the answers at the time. When I was able to act on the answers (~5 hours ago), there was only one. There are no comments on the question, and were no comments on answers until shortly ago when I made the first comment. My fuzzy memory of the notifications (as seen on the app) ~15 hours ago indicated two different answers, and I thought that both contained useful information.

How can I review the answer that was deleted before I got a chance to glean anything from it?

I understand that 10k rep allows users to see deleted questions/answers, but I'm simply trying to see an answer to my own question. If it was abusive or problematic, I have no problem with moderator removal - I'm simply hoping to collect any remotely relevant information to my problem, since I've been attempting to solve this problem for days on end, with little-to-no success.

Comment: Two things I'll say about that:  it was deleted by the answerer themselves after they received a remark that it wasn't complete or correct.  I'm not convinced it's worth your time to look at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was an additional answer on that question which  was neither up-voted nor down-voted, but has a comment on it which states that the answer is wrong.

It has been deleted by the author of the answer afterwards (maybe due to the comment).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying; I suppose I can't fault a user for deleting an answer which was indicated as wrong by another user (not to mention it may have negative reputation repercussions). It may still be useful in troubleshooting, but it's an understandable action - I'm guessing there's no way for me to view it though...(?)

Comment: Unless you are >10k: No. I could post a screenshot of it, but since the answerer decided to delete it himself, I'm not sure it is a good idea to show it here.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It's unfortunate, but understandable. Perhaps a feature could be added to allow original posters to view deleted answers, along with the reason for deletion. It would be educational to also know what *not* to do, as well as what to do. (The internet does contain errant information - if one answer echos a misinformed solution from elsewhere, knowing it is a bad solution may prevent the asker from executing that bad information, if they can see an answer citing said information as bad.) I'll consider this question closed, but it might not be a bad feature request.

Comment: @user3.1415927 I'm not sure if such a feature has been requested before, but if not, feel free to post a [meta-tag:feature-request] for such a thing. The community may well support it.